# Angular 6 and Polyfills.ts

Tags: angular, build, polyfills, ng-build

I have an application of angular 6 and I need it to work in IE10 and IE11, I'm configuring as indicated by the angular web , but I can not make it work in IE when I run "ng build --prod" (with the command "ng serve" no I have problems).

the polyfills file place everything related to IE

Make it work by removing the option "optimization" of the configuration of the prod build and placing the folder "./node_modules/core-js/" in the dist root.

I need to solve the problem without removing this option. it's possible?

I leave the files, angular.json, polyfills.ts and package.json

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sro",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "build-develop": "ng build --base-href=/APP/ --configuration=develop",
    "build-testing": "ng build --base-href=/APP/ --configuration=testing",
    "build-prod": "ng build --base-href=/APP/ --configuration=prod",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.8",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ngx-captcha": "^3.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ngx-spec": "^1.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```js
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
```

In polyfills.ts uncomment this lines :

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

Comment: did you uncommented and installed the packages mentioned by polyfills.ts that are related to IE?

Comment: yes I did, uncomment everything and install the packages.